# When I import OBJ-C classes in swift, Xcode doesn't prompt me to add a Bridging-header.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

When I first import an OBJ-C class into a swift project, Xcode doesn't prompt me to add a bridging-header file.

so I fixed in the same way as in [Swift Bridging Header and visibility of Obj-C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468514/swift-bridging-header-and-visibility-of-obj-c-class)

But when I want to import another Obj-C class, if I do the same thing again, the file's url will be mixed so that Xcode can't distinguish them.

I tried to make a bridging-header file by myself , but didn't work either.
Help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make bridging header manually first create header file. Name it whatever you want. Then Click your project's target and open Build Settings tab and search "Bridging". You will see "Objective-C Bridging Header" option. Double click it and write your bridging header name like this format TargetName/BrdgingFile.h

[image]

Comment: Jesus Christ, it works!! +1 if you find Bridging headers unintuitive!

Comment: if I already have a bridging header for another obj-c library I'm using, can I just add a second import statement to that one?

Answer (score 0):

ok,NOW I fixed this problem and in addition I figured out how "bridging header"file works.

Actually I followed the method of the question I mentioned above, but what I need to drag is **exactly**  the "bridging-header" file, rather than other implicit header file (because you can only  import one header file there.)

So I created a header file called "myproject-bridging-header.h" (actually the name doesn't matter) and dragged it to the item, and in the header file I imported other header files

Bingo! It works smoothly~